# Daisy Chained .replace() with regex - is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, regex, simplify

I am taking a string and checking for multiple problems (exporting to csv, I need to remove things like HTML elements and excessive spaces, etc

here is what I have

```
data.replace( /<a.*btn-sm.*?<\/a>/g, '' )  // get rid of buttons completely
    .replace( /<.*?>/ig, '' )              // get rid of other html tags, keep content
    .replace( '&lt;','<' )                 // convert html to symbol for printing
    .replace( '&gt;','>' )                 // convert html to symbol for printing
    .replace( /\n/g, "," )                 // get rid of newline, replace with comma
    .replace( /\t/g, " " )                 // get rid of tab, replace with space
    .replace( / {1,}/g, " " )              // get rid of consecutive spaces
    .replace( ', ,', "," )                 // get rid of consecutive commas
    .replace( /(^[,\s]+)|([,\s]+$)/g, '' ) // lose trailing and leading commas / spaces
```

is there a simpler way to do this (hopefully keeping it readable to that someone coming in will know what is going on without too much effort)

data could look like this

```
data = '<p>\n\tMark Smith<br />\n\t\t&lt;mark.smith@example.tld&gt;</p>\n<p>\n\t<a href="https://google.com" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Google!</a>      \n</p>\n\n\n';
```

Comment: Which language? JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you only replace the first occurrence of `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and ", ,", but all occurences for all your other calls?

Comment: And note that `' {1,}'` is a complicated way to write `' +'` (and you are already using `+` in other places)

Comment: @knittl , yes, javascript, and only first because I only expect it once in my reuslts, I guess I could make it be greedy, but no need for my case.  the {1.} was from a copied snippet, I am not a regex expert so that is why I came to ask about a cleaner way to do what I was doing

Comment: You probably meant "global" (`…/g`) when you wrote "greedy", right? Regexes are greedy by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is subjective and opinion-based, but one option how this could be written differently (not saying in any way better) is to combine the regular expressions into a single one with alternatives (you were already using an alternative in your last expression):

```
data.replace(/<a.*btn-sm.*?<\/a>|<.*?>|^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '')
    .replace('&lt;','<')
    .replace('&gt;','>')
    .replace(/\n/g, ",")
    .replace(/\t| +/g, " ")
    .replace(', ,', ",")
```

Comment: Tabs aren't removed, they're replaced by spaces. Should be `.replace(/[\t ]+/g, " ")`

Comment: this does look much cleaner, thank you for both the comments above and this block.  Will this trim the before and after if the space / comma are placed after the first replace?

Comment: @Kender I don't understand your question. What do you mean with "will it trim the before and after"?